# Linux command line application with persistent interface

Tags: linux, shell, user-interface, command-line

How do programs (specifically in Linux) like `top` keep their interface on the screen without it scrolling?  Do they create a new `screen` session, or is there a standard library for creating GUIs like that?  If they do use screen, then why is the output still written to stdout when I exit top?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a standard library, it is called [ncurses](http://www.gnu.org/software/ncurses/). But there's no need to use it - the [console_codes(4)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man4/console_codes.4.html) man page describes how to do such things by writing special character sequences to a terminal (emulator), and curses is nothing but a wrapper around that.

To clear the screen like top does, you'll need to echo `ESC [ 2 J` to the terminal to clear it, followed by `ESC [ H` to reset the cursor to the origin, i.e.

```
echo -ne "\033[2J\033[H"
```

Note that top might actually be more intelligent and not redraw the entire screen but only the parts which changed. See the manual page for more details. (You can do more fancy stuff with console codes, like changing colors, underline, bold, or even use the mouse in x terminals.)

Comment: Thanks for the links.  When I try the code you gave, though, the screen is cleared and scrolled.  If I were to call this in my application, it would scroll out of control.  Or does it work differently if I just type that at the command prompt?

Comment: Try using only `echo -ne "\033[H"`.

Comment: That worked!  I also looked into ncurses and that looks like what I would need for a bigger project.  Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Those programs also tend to send `smcup` and `smkx` sequences, to enter an alternate screen buffer with no scrollback, and to make the keypad keys send the appropriate escape sequences. See `terminfo(5)` and **ctlseqs.txt** from the xterm distribution.